# How can I use multiple data streams on 1 page/site? [GA4]

Tags: google-analytics-4

I have a primary GA4 account.

```
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXX"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'G-XXXX');
</script>
```

I need to allow third-party users to embed their analytics on some pages of my site.

Can I do something similar?

```
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXX"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'G-XXXX');
    gtag('config', [[G-XXXX-2]]);
</script>
```

*[[G-XXXX-2]] will be installed by the user in advance, using the tools of my site.
I can't know this id in advance.*

With this approach, how can I send a custom event only to the second stream?

```
gtag('event', '<event_name>', {
  <event_parameters>
});
```

Can I send only 1 custom event to the second stream, and disable the rest?